# Export table from sqlserver and import into oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can we export table from SQL Server and import into Oracle?

Currently I am exporting data into a CSV file and loading into Oracle by using SQL loader.

Is there any other way to do the same.

Comment: This is a bit broad. SQL Server already offers import/export functionality through SSIS. You can use the Import/Export Wizard in SSMS to quickly create an SSIS package that does just that, and later configure it with batching etc. You can use one database as the source and the other as the target to move data directly from one to another. Or you can set up replication between SQL Server and Oracle. Or you can add a [DB Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28277/toc.htm) to SQL Server. Or add Oracle as a linked server in SQL Server

Comment: You can do it with JAVA

You can connect mssql with jdbc driver and get data then insert it to oracle table on oracle jdbc connection.

You can search it on google.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle there is a thing called heterogenous services which will let you query an SQL Server table as if it was an Oracle table.  It is initiated from the Oracle side, and communicates with a remote data source (SQL Server in your case) via ODBC. The remote data source appears within Oracle as a standard database link.

There are some restrictions in terms of datatypes, but it is adequate for many scenarios. Details here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11050/toc.htm